# Find Server Seed from Hash Verification Script

Tags: javascript, html

View this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1L1uqcgv/6/

```
function refreshTable(){
    var hash = document.getElementById("gameHash").value;
    var lastHash = "";
    var amount = document.getElementById("gameAmount").value;

    var tableBody = document.getElementById("tbody");
    tableBody.innerHTML = "";
    for(var i=0; i<amount; i++){
    var gameHash = (lastHash!=""?genGameHash(lastHash):hash);
    var gameCrash = crashPointFromHash((lastHash!=""?genGameHash(lastHash):hash));
    var clr = gameCrash > 1.97 ? 'green': (gameCrash < 1.97 ? 'red' : 'blue');
    tableBody.innerHTML += "<tr><td>"+gameHash+"</td><td style='background:" + clr + "'>"+gameCrash+"</td></tr>";
    
    lastHash = gameHash;
    }
}


function divisible(hash, mod) {
// So ABCDEFGHIJ should be chunked like  AB CDEF GHIJ
var val = 0;

var o = hash.length % 4;
for (var i = o > 0 ? o - 4 : 0; i < hash.length; i += 4) {
    val = ((val << 16) + parseInt(hash.substring(i, i+4), 16)) % mod;
}

return val === 0;
}

function genGameHash(serverSeed) {
    return CryptoJS.SHA256(serverSeed).toString()
};


function hmac(key, v) {
    var hmacHasher = CryptoJS.algo.HMAC.create(CryptoJS.algo.SHA256, key);
    return hmacHasher.finalize(v).toString();
}

function crashPointFromHash(serverSeed) {
// see: provably fair seeding event
var hash = hmac(serverSeed, '000000000000000007a9a31ff7f07463d91af6b5454241d5faf282e5e0fe1b3a');

// In 1 of 101 games the game crashes instantly.
if (divisible(hash, 101))
    return 0;

// Use the most significant 52-bit from the hash to calculate the crash point
var h = parseInt(hash.slice(0,52/4),16);
var e = Math.pow(2,52);

return (Math.floor((100 * e - h) / (e - h))/100).toFixed(2);
};
```

Is it possible to find the "serverSeed" as shown in lines 31 and 41?
To find previous games, a hash is entered into the box, showing all previous games. Would serverSeed be used to find these hashes, or does the single hash create all previous hashes?

Comment: what is the point of hmac if you hard-code half the input?

Comment: it looks like the only real input is a number

Comment: Number or hash? Then what is the point of "serverSeed?"

Answer (score 0):

The ServerSeed is the hash you input in order to see the crash point and to view the previous games.